# How to use one method for various same type objects in python?

Tags: python, object, python-3.x

For example, I have many turtles and I want them all move to forward. Should I repeat my forward command for each turtle or there is a Pythonic way?

```
import turtle
tx=turtle.Turtle()
ty=turtle.Turtle()
tz=turtle.Turtle()
ti=turtle.Turtle()
tj=turtle.Turtle()
tx.fd()
ty.fd()
tz.fd()
ti.fd()
tj.fd()
```

Is there any functions like `map` to use `fd()` method then write my objects name? I know it's better to use a list and the `map` function but I want to name my objects.

Comment: If you want the turtles to have names, why not use a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
turtles = [tx, ty, tz, ti, tj]
for turtle in turtles:
    turtle.fd()
```

I'd still recommend not giving them their own variables, but it's your call. Also, `map` is not a good idea for functions you want to execute for side effects; if you don't iterate over the whole map object somehow, the function won't get called on all the things you want it to be called on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary for naming and use loop on the values:

```
import turtule
t_names = ['tx', 'ty', 'tz', 'ti', 'tj']
t = dict([(name, turtle.Turtle()) for name in t_names])
[one_t.fd() for one_t in t.values()]
```

and use them by name:

```
t['tz'].bw()
```